# OpenShift on OpenStack

Tags: openshift-origin

Start of master fails with error:

6109 start_master.go:103] could not init cloud provider "openstack": Post http://10.175.1.110:5000/v2.0/tokens: dial tcp 10.175.1.110:5000: i/o timeout

The IP address in the request is not correct,it is the keystone "internal" endpoint, it should be "public".

Why is "internal" endpoint coming to use with start_master.go, and how to enforce usage of "public" one?

When using HEAT template to create OpenShift, public endpoint was specified for
--parameter os_auth_url

That public endpoint is not in any config file on the system (not in master config file, not in cloud-init conf files).
It looks like the URL is somehow dynamically created, but from what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL can be specified in /etc/origin/cloudprovider
and right selection of endpoint works if keystone v3 api is used, e.g.

```
https://<URL>:5000/v3
```